# Data source for subreport's subreport in jasper

Tags: jasper-reports, datasource, subreport

I have a main report which includes a subreport1 and inside this subreport1 there is subreport called subreport2.

(Main HAS subreport1 HAS subreport2)

Main report sends a JRBeanCollectionDataSource($P{Collection}.getData()) to subreport1 and this collection is nothing but collection of object Cars.

So for my subreport2 datasource i would like to set Object car as a datasource from subreport1

Can someone please help me with how to set only one record(or current record) from subreport1 to subreport 2

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!